# Json.NET Deserialisation - key value pairs?

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently having some trouble deserialising a collection of names key/value pairs using Json.NET

Here's an example of the Json I'm trying to work with:

```
"prices":
{
    "SharedMinPrice":{"USD":"0.00"},
    "SharedAveragePrice":{"USD":"0.00"},
    "PrivateMinPrice":{"USD":"8.82"},
    "PrivateAveragePrice":{"USD":"26.85"},
    "MinPrice":{"USD":"8.82"},
    "AveragePrice":{"USD":"26.85"}}
}
```

If I try to deserialise this to a List of a custom type, I get the following error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[APITypes.PropertyPrice]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

I'm using the following code in my backing class:

```
[JsonProperty("prices")]
    public List<PropertyPrice> Prices { get; set; }
```

and my PropertyPrice class is:

```
    internal class PropertyPrice
{

    [JsonProperty("sharedMinPrice")]
    public float sharedMinPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sharedAveragePrice")]
    public float sharedAveragePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("privateMinPrice")]
    public float privateMinPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("privateAveragePrice")]
    public float privateAveragePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("minPrice")]
    public float minPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("averagePrice")]
    public float averagePrice { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: you have two '}}' after "AveragePrice".. Did you miss an opening '{' ?

Comment: The reason your code is not working is very simple. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not an array, you can use `Dictionary<string,T>`  for this. This code works...

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Price>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Prices["SharedMinPrice"]["USD"]);
```

..

```
public class Price
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>> Prices { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deserialize JSON of the form `{"USD": 3.50}` into a `float`.  Those types don't match up. Below I define a new type `MoneyAmount` which does.

```
internal class MoneyAmount
{
    public float USD { get; set; }
}

internal class PropertyPrice
{

    [JsonProperty("sharedMinPrice")]
    public MoneyAmount sharedMinPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sharedAveragePrice")]
    public MoneyAmount sharedAveragePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("privateMinPrice")]
    public MoneyAmount privateMinPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("privateAveragePrice")]
    public MoneyAmount privateAveragePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("minPrice")]
    public MoneyAmount minPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("averagePrice")]
    public MoneyAmount averagePrice { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Dictionary<string, float>` in place of `MoneyAmount` if you want to handle all kinds of currencies dynamically.

Comment: Most probably, json would contain other currencies. What about, for ex, `"SharedMinPrice":{"EUR":"0.00"},`

Comment: @L.B Yes, but that wasn't the problem the asker was having. The problem the asker was having is that the JSON structure and the .NET type he was trying to deserialize into didn't match.

Comment: Of course, but you posted an answer that would **only** work for this sample, not a generic answer.  I don't think it's what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the opening { at the beginning

{"prices": {"SharedMinPrice":{"USD":"0.00"},"SharedAveragePrice":{"USD":"0.00"},"PrivateMinPrice":{"USD":"8.82"},"PrivateAveragePrice":{"USD":"26.85"},"MinPrice":{"USD":"8.82"},"AveragePrice":{"USD":"26.85"}}}

--> use something like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to test your json when it doesn't deserialize

Additionally, you are not passing it in as an array:

```
{"employees": [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not an array type, it should look something like this:

```
"prices":
{   
    "SharedMinPrice":{"USD":"0.00"},
    "SharedAveragePrice":{"USD":"0.00"},
    "PrivateMinPrice":{"USD":"8.82"},
    "PrivateAveragePrice":{"USD":"26.85"},
    "MinPrice":{"USD":"8.82"},
    "AveragePrice":{"USD":"26.85"}}
}
```